# Not getting exact result using the DrawImage function

Tags: c#, drawimage, tiles-game

Okay, so I have an Image which holds my tile set. Then I have my PictureBox used as my "game screen". All the code does is takes a snippet of my tile set (a tile) and place it on the game screen.

Here's my code.

```
private void picMap_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            //screenMain = picMap.CreateGraphics();

            // Create image.
            //gfxTiles = Image.FromFile(@Program.resourceMapFilePath + "poatiles.png");

            // Create coordinates for upper-left corner of image. 
            int x = 0;
            int y = 0;

            // Create rectangle for source image.
            Rectangle srcRect = new Rectangle(16, 16, 16, 16);
            GraphicsUnit units = GraphicsUnit.Pixel;

            // Draw image to screen.
            screenMain.DrawImage(gfxTiles, x, y, srcRect, units);
            screenMain.DrawImage(gfxTiles, 16, 0, srcRect, units);
            screenMain.DrawImage(gfxTiles, 32, 0, srcRect, units);
            screenMain.DrawImage(gfxTiles, 16, 16, srcRect, units);
        }
```

And here is my output: [image: http://tm14.net/pokestory/mapeditor_test.png]

Any reason why that space between each "tile" is there (it's a 2 pixels gap)? I could ghetto rig the code, but I plan to use algebra to programatically figure out where tiles need to go, etc etc, so a ghetto rig would work, but to do that throughout the entire game would be troublesome, and at the very least, sloppy.

Comment: Ty for the formatting edit. :) I'll try to be better about it in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the call to DrawImage is okay. In the image you posted it looks like 16x16 tiles next to each other. I'd check poatiles.png. I'm not sure what's at Rectangle(16, 16, 16, 16) in it. It may not be what you think.

EDIT: I don't know what to say. I made a png almost the size of poatiles and put a 16x16 square in it a 16,16, and it drew exactly like you'd expect.

The code looks fine and since it works on smaller images, the only thing I can think of is there's a problem with poatiles.

There's the following comment in MSDN about Graphics.DrawImage Method (Image, Int32, Int32, Rectangle, GraphicsUnit)

> This method draws a portion of an image using its physical size, so
>   the image portion will have its correct size in inches regardless of
>   the resolution (dots per inch) of the display device. For example,
>   suppose an image portion has a pixel width of 216 and a horizontal
>   resolution of 72 dots per inch. If you call this method to draw that
>   image portion on a device that has a resolution of 96 dots per inch,
>   the pixel width of the rendered image portion will be (216/72)*96 =
>   288.

Since you're specifying pixels as the unit I'd expect it to ignore that. But in the absence of better ideas you might want to compare the dpi of poatiles versus the smaller images. (Image.HorizontalResolution & Image.VerticalResolution)

Comment: I could post the tile sheet. But all it is are 16 x 16 tiles in a sheet. There's no black around that tile. It just decided that it wants to show a black space around it. That's the tile in it's entirety, just extra space is being added and I have no idea why.

Comment: I wish I could edit my other comment, but I can't... But, the original tile sheet is 256x9616... I made two sample images that would be smaller, a 16 x 16 (just that one tile) and a 64 x 32 sheet. Each of the smaller sheets display the tile as intended, no gaps or anything. But, the biggest tile sheet seems to have the issue... I thought that was strange behavior.

Comment: After adding the code to  print the information you said to gather, I got the output of:

119.9896, 119.9896 &
95.9866, 95.9866

The fist one is the vertical and horizontal of the tiles I'm trying to use. The second one is the smaller image. Does that mean I should recreate the first file and see if I can't get it to behave? It was created in XP for use in a VB6 project, so it actually came from a VB6 picture box control I copied and pasted into Paint.

Comment: Can no longer edit. Gah, I'm sorry. Instead of just speculating, I should have just tried it... I recreated the image (Copied the old one, into a new file) and guess what: it worked. Thank you so much! I'd upvote if I could. You're the man. *thumbs up*

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that all of the information is there to start with, but here's some suggestions I have from looking at what you've done so far.

1) Check poatiles.png to make sure that it's definitely a 16x16 pixel image with no black pixels around it.

2) It seems odd that your Rectangle has four int's in its constructor. A rectangle should usually only have a width and height (if any sides have different lengths, then it's not a true rectangle!)

3) You might want to determine your positions on screen by multiplying by width and height of the Rectangle that you're trying to draw and adding that value to the origin (0,0).

Comment: The first two args of that Rectangle constructor are x and y locations. The rectangle is the rectangular region of the image to draw. That call to DrawImage doesn't draw all of the image. I assume poatiles.png contains multiple tiles.